# Defining different abstract layout for different tabs in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework

Can I have 2 states with abstract:true i.e base layout for different tabs?

Forexample, 
for tab-1, tab-2 and tab-3, I need to have `tabs.html` as abstract:true in state provider and for tab-4, I need to have menu.html as abstract:true in state provder so that subsequent states inherit from it.

Something like this:

```js
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

      // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
      // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
      // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
      // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
      $stateProvider

      // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
        .state('tab', {
        url: '/tab',
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
      })

      // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

      .state('tab.dash', {
        url: '/dash',
        views: {
          'tab-dash': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html',
            controller: 'DashCtrl'
          }
        }
      })

      .state('tab.chats', {
          url: '/chats',
          views: {
            'tab-chats': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/tab-chats.html',
              controller: 'ChatsCtrl'
            }
          }
        })
        .state('tab.chat-detail', {
          url: '/chats/:chatId',
          views: {
            'tab-chats': {
              templateUrl: 'templates/chat-detail.html',
              controller: 'ChatDetailCtrl'
            }
          }
        })

      .state('tab.account', {
        url: '/account',
        views: {
          'tab-account': {
            templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html',
            controller: 'AccountCtrl'
          }
        }
      })
      $stateProvider
        .state('app', {
          abstract: true,
          templateUrl: "templates/menu.html"
        })

      .state('app.events', {
        url: "/events",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            templateUrl: "templates/events.html",
            controller: 'EventsCtrl'

          }
        }
      })
```

tabs.html looks like this:

```html
<!--
    Create tabs with an icon and label, using the tabs-positive style.
    Each tab's child <ion-nav-view> directive will have its own
    navigation history that also transitions its views in and out.
    -->
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Chats Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Chats" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/chats">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-chats"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Account Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!--Practice Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Events" icon-off="ion-ios-arrow-forward " icon-on="ion-ios-arrow-forward-utline" href="#/tab/events">
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>


</ion-tabs>
```

menu.html:

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="true">
  <ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>

      <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left">
        </button>
      </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-side-menu-content>

  <ion-side-menu side="left">
    <ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
      <h1 class="title">My app</h1>
    </ion-header-bar>
    <ion-content scroll="false">
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item nav-clear menu-close href="#/events">
          Events
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```

It does not work though.Is it possible to do it? If not what are the alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add multiple abstract states.

Here is the [Documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-and-Nested-Views#abstract-states) for Angular states. According to the docs:

> An abstract state can have child states but can not get activated itself. An 'abstract' state is simply a state that can't be transitioned to. It is activated implicitly when one of its descendants are activated.